# Why "dog-eats-dog" cannot be a phrasal adjective but "dog-eat-dog" can?

Tags: adjectives

Dog eats dog sounds correct but it's not an adjective here. As soon as it becomes an adjective we remove *s* from *eats*, Why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104235/discussion-on-question-by-bp2017-why-dog-eats-dog-cannot-be-a-phrasal-adjectiv).

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives in English don't change to agree with the noun like they do in some other languages.

So if a noun is used as an adjective, it will be the singular form.

> I have three cars.
>
> I have three car decals.

It's easy to get mixed up because possessive nouns can be used attributively as adjectives and will keep the `'s`.  So this sounds like an exception in speech but isn't.

> I have the three cars' decals = I have the decals that belong to the three cars.

Comment: Yes but “eats“ has nothing to do with plural form.

Comment: Yes it does. _Eats_ is singular form, which has plenty to do with plural form.

Comment: @JohnLawler - sure eats is singular as well as dog is. So why in “dog eat dog” the singular form “eats” is not used?

Comment: First, asking "Why?" a particular language feature exists is a waste of time; we don't know why. Second, the form _dog-eat-dog_ is not a sentence (which is where agreement comes in), but a fixed adjectival phrase with no internal syntax. Nobody was around taking notes when it was first used, so we don't know when, how, who, or why.